# Why won't my site load from one computer, but it will another?

Tags: dns

Pretty vague title, but basically I can only get "my site" to load from one computer. I've purchased hosting and a domain name, set it all up, and there's nothing there yet, but the default directory browser thing shows up when I go to the url on my work computer, but from my home computer and a virtual machine it doesn't... what should I look at to troubleshoot? Everything else works fine from home, so I wouldn't think it would be a router issue or anything like that.

Thoughts?

UPDATE: It works from my work computer, and a friend of mine's computer at her house, but not on my PC or laptop... I've tried rebooting, unplugging cable modem and router and plugging them back in, dnsflush, turning windows firewall off, and everything i can think of... i don't have any idea what to do now

UPDATE: This is interesting... when I tracert from my computer it stops and gives Request Time Out one hop before getting to the actual web server. When I do the tracert using dnsstuff.com, it makes the hop just fine and shows the web server on there... I don't get it.

Comment: Is your domain new? Conventional wisdom is that it takes 24-48 hours for DNS changes to propogate.

Comment: this would be more appropriate on superuser.

Comment: @Peter, yeah I voted to put it there to.. just wasn't thinking... i default to here lol

Comment: Now you go and get some fresh air, come back in 20 minutes or so with a fresh mind, and solve the problem by correcting some silly mistake you have made :)

Comment: Max: Re your last edit - It's a firewall stopping you.

Comment: How can I fix it... how can I find out what's stopping it when windows firewall is turned off

Comment: What exactly happens when you mean it doesn't load... are you getting a 404 or what?

Comment: Oh, I thought I had put that in the question. I get a timeout. In firefox it says this:

The connection has timed out

The server at www.bickfordtools.com is taking too long to respond.

Comment: Also, it works from both my PC, my laptop over wireless, and my virtual ubuntu instance running on my pc.

Comment: @Max: "Also, it works from both my PC, my laptop over wireless, and my virtual ubuntu instance running on my pc. " : I thought it wasn't working from your home computers, but was working at work. Is it the opposite?

Comment: Just tried www.bickfordtools.com, I get a directory listing.

Comment: @JRL, sorry i mixed up my words.... doesn't work from all of those things

Comment: Everyone seems to get a directory listing except me... This is retarded

Comment: I have a similar issue. I have updated the name server for the domain, and I have two computers on the same network (at home) - one resolves the domain, and the other does not! ipconfig /flushdns didn't help, and there is nothing in my host files. I assume this problem will fix itself in a few hours, but I am just really puzzled as to how two computers going to the internet through the same router can act differently. Will be grateful for insights.

Answer (score 4):

Check out: http://www.dnsstuff.com/; you may also try `ipconfig /flushdns`.

Comment: I've done this, although it shouldn't really matter (and it didn't) since it is resolving to the correct IP address

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. Turns out I had overridden the IP address in my hosts file (which is why it only had issues on one computer). On a mac /etc/hosts, on PC \system32\drivers\etc\hosts

You'll need admin privileges to change the file sudo vim /etc/hosts (or nano or some other editer) or open the hosts file on windows by first opening notepad as an administrator then navigating to the file location (choose the option to view all files, not just text files).

I had something like this in my hosts file:

```
104.200.18.XXX    mywebsite.com    www.mywebsite.com
```

I did a traceroute to my website and it displayed the incorrect IP address which is how I realized I had changed my hosts file.

Just remove the whole line and save.

Comment: NOTICE: after the dns will be updated for your pc (probably 12-48 hrs), then you should remove that record from `HOSTS` file.

Answer (score 2):

DNS can take time to kick in. 36hrs is worst case scenario

Comment: The DNS works fine. I can't even get to it with the IP address. The DNS also resolves to the same IP as it does at work

Comment: Max: Depending on your host headers; you won't be able to get to it just using the IP (you'll need to set up the domain in your own local `hosts` file first).

Comment: Putting it in the hosts file didn't help

Comment: Max: I recommend moving this question to the correct forum (as I've suggested in my close request), they can probably better help you there.

Comment: Max: But if, logically, the IP is reachable from this machine, and the hosts file is set up (and being used) then, you must test that a `telnet` to the appropriate port works; if it does, then well, it won't. If it doesn't, it's firewall related.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. After the whole day of trying different things, i found the problem and solution.

On Windows , do a "ping yoursite.com" command and see if you recieve a reply or not. {I didn't, it directly showed time out}

I have a router, so problem was in DNS settings of router, i changed it to google's public dns {8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4} and was able to connect to the site.

hope this helps someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

use a bottom up approach to find the problem. First verify the network in this sequence.

1) Check your physical connection is working (duh, should be). Check your arp table for any problems. Better still, just flush it with arp -d *

2) Check if your route is working to the destination. traceroute to the destination. Are there any difference ? Any routers in the middle routing differently ?

3) Check if the transport is working. Check your firewall, intruder detector or any other transport level service to verify you can indeed send a TCP packet on port 80 to your destination.

If all pass, then i am stumped ..

Answer (score 0):

Try using IE instead of Firefox and see if it makes a difference, or vice versa.

Comment: tried both... it happens on both browsers on both computers... i'm pretty sure it's a router issue

Answer (score 0):

**Work computer using VPN? Or directly connected to workplace network?**

I had this problem aswell ... that's how I found  this question ;)

The new DNS was found when browsing to the site on my android, nearly instantly, but I was redirected to the old nameservers when browsed to the site on my work computer.

I quickly realised that I'm using a VPN connection on my work computer, which means my traffic is rerouted through employer network, so ipconfig/flushdns wasn't helping.

But, as soon as I disconnected VPN, I was browsing through my personal internet provider, and voila.. I was seing content on the new DNS.